# Why does my Elasticsearch multi-match query look only for prefixes?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to write an Elasticsearch multi-match query (with the Java API) to create a "search-as-you-type" program. The query is applied to two fields, `title` and `description`, which are analyzed as ngrams.

My problem is, it seems that Elasticsearch tries to find only words **beginning** like my query. For instance, if I search for "nut", then it matches with documents featuring "*nut*", "*nuts*", "*Nutella*", etc, but it does not match documents featuring "*walnut*", which **should** be matched.

Here are my settings :

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "edgeNGramAnalyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "edgeTokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "word_delimiter",
                        "lowercase",
                        "unique"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "edgeTokenizer": {
                  "type": "edgeNGram",
                  "min_gram": "3",
                  "max_gram": "8",
                  "token_chars": [
                    "letter",
                    "digit"
                  ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of my mapping :

```
{
    "content": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "edgeNGramAnalyzer",
                "fields": {
                    "sort": { 
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "edgeNGramAnalyzer",
                "fields": {
                    "sort": { 
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my query :

```
new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(query).field("title", 3).field("description", 1).fuzziness(0).tieBreaker(1).minimumShouldMatch("100%")
```

Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using an [`edgeNGram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer instead of [`nGram`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) one. The former only indexes prefixes, while the latter will index prefixes, suffixes and also sub-parts of your data.

Change your analyzer definition to this instead and it should work as expected:

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "edgeNGramAnalyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "edgeTokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "word_delimiter",
                        "lowercase",
                        "unique"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "edgeTokenizer": {
                  "type": "nGram",         <---- change this
                  "min_gram": "3",
                  "max_gram": "8",
                  "token_chars": [
                    "letter",
                    "digit"
                  ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works, you saved me hours of debugging !